# How to add a jar file located in root folder to library dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, build, jar, dependencies, sbt

I have a case where I need to a jar file located in root folder of the project.

[image]
 I have tried the below :

```
"ccp.mts.test" % "mts-test_2.12-0.2" % "2.0" from "/mts-test_2.12-0.2.jar"
```

It did not work. Then I tried like below :

```
unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/mts-test_2.12-0.2.jar")
```

This also didn't work.

How can I do it?

Comment: how did you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the `file` protocol. Try the following

```
libraryDependencies += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjrt" % "1.9.2" from ("file://./aspectjrt-1.9.2.jar")
```

EDIT

I am modifying my answer based on your comment.

In order to provide the absolute path, you can use the following code snippet

```
val currentDirectory = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath
libraryDependencies += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjrt" % "1.9.2" from ("file://" + currentDirectory + "/aspectjrt-1.9.2.jar")
```

Comment: I am getting the error like below after trying the above `ccp.mts.test#mts-test_2.12-0.2;2.0!mts-test_2.12-0.2.jar origin location must be absolute: \mts-test_2.12-0.2.jar`

Comment: Please check the new solution

Comment: Tried, still same issue coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, a work-around is to go to `C:\Users\myuser\.ivy2\cache\ccp.mts.test\mts-test\ivydata-2.8.0.properties` (change `myuser` and `ivydata-2.8.0` as appropritate). Then edit the file which should look something like this:

```
artifact\:ccp.mts.test\#jar\#jar\#2009603053.location=\\mydirectory\\lib\\mts-test_2.12-0.2.jar
artifact\:ccp.mts.test\#jar\#jar\#2009603053.exists=true
artifact\:ccp.mts.test\#jar\#jar\#2009603053.is-local=true
resolver=sbt-chain
```

and change the first line to

```
artifact\:ccp.mts.test\#jar\#jar\#2009603053.location=C\:\\mydirectory\\lib\\mts-test_2.12-0.2.jar
```